# Unable to compile pattern matching program for list

Tags: java, design-patterns, matcher

I'm trying to build a list and increment a counter for each list item that has a particular keyword. I'm unable to compile this. Why?

```
        int count = 0;
        String keyword = args[1];

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(keyword);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(p);

        /* For each paragraph in the document... */
        for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphs) {
            /* Add to List */
            words.add(paragraph.getText());
            System.out.println(paragraph);

            /* Iterate keyword count */
            while (m.find()) {
                count++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Can you show us the pattern you are using for your regex?

Comment: The second p in ``Matcher m = p.matcher(p);`` is red underlined with CharSequence cannot be applied to Pattern... and yes, the answer below is correct.

Comment: Still your regex logic itself may have problems, hence you should have posted this as well.

Comment: if the answer is correct, please accept it

Comment: Yes the answer is correct in that it now compiles. The problem solved was the poor syntax. Tim brings up a good point about my regex pattern, however. Searching for "Platform", for example, may bring up, say 56 results if there are 55 instances of "Platforms" and 1 instance of "Platform"... because Platform is embedded in Platforms. This is something I will continue to solve.

Comment: you can add a white space indicator (\s) to the beginning and end of the search word

Comment: Given that they are long convoluted URLs there will be no whitespaces... XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably here

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(p);
```

the argument should be the text to search

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(paragraph.getText());
```